# How to read object of object in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a object like

```
private _nodeTypesProps=  {
        id: newId,
        active: false,
        name: "",
        color: "",
        character: "",
        props: {
            description: true,
            notes: true,
            lastModified: true,
            senstiveInformation: true,
            calculation: true
        }
    }
```

I want to read props in template

```
<input [(ngModel)]="_nodeTypesProps.props.description" type="checkbox" id="description"/>
```

Can any body help me how to read nested properties in object.

Comment: That looks right to me ... are you getting an error or something?

Comment: yes getting error description of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you could use '?' to get rid of the error

```
<input [(ngModel)]="_nodeTypesProps?.props?.description" type="checkbox" id="description"/>
```

Comment: getting further errors 
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 37 in [_nodeTypesProps?.props?.description=$event] in AdministrationComponent@108:35

Comment: Glad it works, you can edit the answer with your final code, it could be useful! (I guess it's <input [ngModel]="_nodeTypesProps?.props?.description" (ngModelChange)="_nodeTypesProps.props.description = $event" type="checkbox" id="description"/> but if you can confirm)